# how to produce enode from node key?

Tags: go-ethereum

What is the algorithm to produce a bootnode's enode url ?

For example, I have this data:

```
Node key:  59233b25bfa4c214a8713e07a395a5d11478de10f36c6c80ba5369541f73bc44
IP: 127.0.0.1
Port: 30303
```

From these 3 fields how do I create the enode url ? What is the process?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

On a practical front, you can generate the Enode from the node key using Geth's *bootnode* utility:

```
> /usr/local/bin/bootnode -nodekeyhex 59233b25bfa4c214a8713e07a395a5d11478de10f36c6c80ba5369541f73bc44 -writeaddress
c636515b084e5dcfb39c0e00e3d0dd5b5c4ba7c04d9a4adc3aad4eea6ab25561f0fa09fce119e2aebdcfa34d02a3c8f551b814e31df6940fa937f16e0624fc40
```

The enode URL is then constructed like this:

```
enode://ENODE@IP:PORT
```

I.e.
`enode://c636515b084e5dcfb39c0e00e3d0dd5b5c4ba7c04d9a4adc3aad4eea6ab25561f0fa09fce119e2aebdcfa34d02a3c8f551b814e31df6940fa937f16e0624fc40@127.0.0.1:30303`

---

If you want to know the actual calculation, the source code from Geth works as follows.

*bootnode* executes [this line](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/479aa61f11724560c63a7b56084259552892819d/cmd/bootnode/main.go#L81)
 to process the input `nodeKeyHex` from the command line parameter into `nodeKey`:

```
nodeKey, err = crypto.HexToECDSA(*nodeKeyHex)
```

After this, `nodeKey.PublicKey` is the Public Key (which is the enode) generated from the Private Key (which is the node key) using [this function](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/f272879e5ac464b7260e898c0de0721c46d59195/crypto/crypto.go#L93):

```
func toECDSA(d []byte, strict bool) (*ecdsa.PrivateKey, error) {
    priv := new(ecdsa.PrivateKey)
    priv.PublicKey.Curve = S256()
    if strict && 8*len(d) != priv.Params().BitSize {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("invalid length, need %d bits", priv.Params().BitSize)
    }
    priv.D = new(big.Int).SetBytes(d)
    priv.PublicKey.X, priv.PublicKey.Y = priv.PublicKey.Curve.ScalarBaseMult(d)
    return priv, nil
}
```

Comment: never thought the keys of the nodes are private. thanks!

Comment: Yes - if you need to (re)generate the enode, you can read the nodekey in from a file with the `-nodekey` flag to *bootnode*. This is a bit more secure (the nodekey won't appear in your shell history).

Comment: If one is curious about the process of creating the public key from the private key (aka nodeKeyHex), its documented here (https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/app-notes/index.mvp/id/5767)