# bootnode : relation between boot.key and enode URL

Tags: bootnodes

I'm deploying a bootnode using puppeth utility, but I cannot retrieve the enode url. I think I have the boot.key file generated by puppeth, but I'm not sure it's the right one.
What's the function that takes as input the boot.key and returns the enode:// ... ?
I've tested some hashing algorithms (sha512, sha3-512 ...) but none of those seem to be the good one.

Thank's in advance for your replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the same question asked and answered in the link above: 
[how to produce enode from node key?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28970/how-to-produce-enode-from-node-key)