# Bootnode failure!

Tags: bootnodes

I have tried to create bootnode by using the following command, but I cannot start the node. 
    bootnode -genkey boot.key

```
bootnode -nodekey boot.key -verbosity 9 -addr :30310
INFO [11-20|18:06:05.376] New local node record   seq=1 
id=14a0c68dfe9d6ca2 ip=<nil> udp=0 tcp=0
```

I know how to get the enode, and I had tried to enter it directly. it does not work as well.

```
geth -bootnodes "enode://3ec4fef2d726c2c01f16f0a0030f15dd5a81e274067af2b2157cafbf76aa79fa9c0be52c6664e80cc5b08162ede53279bd70ee10d024fe86613b0b09e1106c40@[::]:30310"
```

Had spent more than 2 days. Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You may produce the enode from nodekey by using option of `--writeaddress`

Refer to 
[how to produce enode from node key?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28970/how-to-produce-enode-from-node-key)

Comment: Hello: Thank you for the reply. I have tried this, but it does not work. I directly enter it into the geth -bootnodes command, but it does not give me the correct p2p network. When I check it, its p2p enode is different from what I entered. Don't know why...

Answer (score 0):

Try to `-writeaddress`

Example: `bootnode -nodekey boot.key -verbosity 9 -addr :30310 -writeaddress`

Maybe it help you

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use it, but it only prints the "73de589f2a9a09b59c1f6b0b3518d6cf66740c2de6aca113ebf057278686263dcdd291bff46fb7225f5fcba3afb680fe8023b8b66b8975763c4f1f0e85321405". I don't know why it is not activated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you find the answer? I have same issure

Comment: I feel like no one really understands the situation that we are facing...

Answer (score 0):

the same to you.
I think this is because your private net have not public net ip.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `[::]` with the IP of the bootnode in `geth -bootnodes "enode://3ec4fef2d726c2c01f16f0a0030f15dd5a81e274067af2b2157cafbf76aa79fa9c0be52c6664e80cc5b08162ede53279bd70ee10d024fe86613b0b09e1106c40@[::]:30310"` and it should work.

(127.0.0.1 if you're running them on the same host or different IP if you're running on a different host)

**Example:**

```
geth -bootnodes "enode://3ec4fef2d726c2c01f16f0a0030f15dd5a81e274067af2b2157cafbf76aa79fa9c0be52c6664e80cc5b08162ede53279bd70ee10d024fe86613b0b09e1106c40@127.0.0.1:30310"
```

or if the IP of the machine running the bootnode is `172.10.20.30`

```
geth -bootnodes "enode://3ec4fef2d726c2c01f16f0a0030f15dd5a81e274067af2b2157cafbf76aa79fa9c0be52c6664e80cc5b08162ede53279bd70ee10d024fe86613b0b09e1106c40@172.10.20.30:30310"
```

Comment: @Steve Hrimatas Make sure you remove any existing Ethereum data directory (usually `/root/.ethereum`) for the node (light/ full/ miner) that you're trying to fire up. I had faced the same issue. Usually, such config changes won't take effect if the node already has existing data. Let me know if this helps.