# Boot Node issue

Tags: go-ethereum, private-blockchain, bootnodes

When I create a bootnode, I am not getting the enode. So I used [this](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/28970/how-to-produce-enode-from-node-key) link for reference to derive it. However, the below is happening. It seems that the bootnode address is 128 bits whereas it is expecting 256.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it right but the third command you are running is useless.

```
bootnode -nodekey boot.key -writeaddress
```

will print your bootnode enode, and you can then get the enode url using :

```
enode@ip:port
```

The param `-nodekeyhex` as to be used instead of `-nodekey` if you generated a hexadecimal boot key.